# structure errror in C error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘.’ token

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization, list-initialization

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct car{

    unsigned char buf[1024];
    int index;
    int hdr;
    int len;
    int dlms_detected;

}frma ;

    int main()
    {
        frma dms;
        dms.buf[1024] = {0x21,0x01,0x12,0x00};
        dms.len  = ( (dms.buf[3] << 8 ) | dms.buf[2] );
        printf("%d",dms.len);
        return 0;
    }
```

I compiled the above code and got the below error

```
main.c:20:17: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
   20 | dms.buf[1024] = {0x21,0x01,0x12,0x00};
```

I have declared structure and has given semicolon for every line still getting the error ,someone pls tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: You can't assign to an array, only copy to it. I suggest you invest in some decent beginners books and read more about basic array handling.

Comment: `frma dms = {.buf = {0x21,0x01,0x12,0x00}};` Use a named-initializer for `buf`.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly the assignment operator is not defined for arrays in C. And secondly this expression `dms.buf[1024]` having the type unsigned char is trying to access memory beyond the declared array So this statement

```
    dms.buf[1024] = {0x21,0x01,0x12,0x00};
```

is incorrect.

You could initialize the array when the object `dms` is declared as for example

```
    frma dms =
    {
        .buf = {0x21,0x01,0x12,0x00}
    };
    dms.len  = ( (dms.buf[3] << 8 ) | dms.buf[2] );
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me,But how is the statement access more memory beyond allocated coz I have allocated 1024 byte and only using 4 byte right?sorry if this is a stupid question but please help me so that I can understand.

Comment: @dcu You initialized explicitly 4 bytes. All other bytes are initialized implicitly by zero.